# SOAP with Entity class

Tags: java, web-services, ejb, entity, jax-ws

I have this Entity class:

```
package com.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.EmbeddedId;
import javax.persistence.Entity
import com.model.BaseEntity;
import com.model.CustomerPK;

@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER")
public class Customer extends BaseEntity {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -625869124375935833L;
    
    @EmbeddedId
    private CustomerPK id;
    
    @Column(name = "NAME", length = 70, nullable = true)
    private String name;
    
    @Column(name = "PHONE", length = 20, nullable = true)
    private String phone;
    
    @Column(name = "ADDRESS", length = 40, nullable = true)
    private String address;
    
    @Column(name = "CITY", length = 30, nullable = true)
    private String city;
    
    ....
    
}
```

And I have this Web Service class:

```
package com.ws;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import com.servico.WSService;

import com.model.Customer;


@WebService(serviceName = "customerWS")
public class CustomerWS {

    @Inject
    private WSService wss;

    @WebMethod(operationName = "validateCustomer")
    public List<String> validateCustomer(
            @XmlElement(name = "customer", required = true) Customer customer) {
        return wss.validateCustomer(customer);
    }
}
```

When I try to start the service this error is shown:

```
Caused by: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Two classes have the same XML type name "{http://--.--.-----.-----.-----.----.----.--/}baseEntity". Use @XmlType.name and @XmlType.namespace to assign different names to them.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at ------.BaseEntity
        at ------.model.BaseEntity

    this problem is related to the following location:
        at ------.model.BaseEntity
```

I cannot edit the BaseEntity class. Is there a way to create the Web Service without annotate the BaseEntity class?

### **EDIT:**

I don't want to use MOXy framework because I already have the Web Service online. My througs is if I can marshaller only the Customer class, without her BaseEntity class.
Additional info: My client and my Web Service have access to the same package where Customer class is located.

Comment: How did you generate the JAX-WS classes?

Comment: Wich JAX-WS class? The CustomerWS class I generate manually.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting the JAXB exception like "Two classes have the same XML type name..."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132789/getting-the-jaxb-exception-like-two-classes-have-the-same-xml-type-name)

Answer (score 0):

If you can use MOXy, then there is [option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132789/getting-the-jaxb-exception-like-two-classes-have-the-same-xml-type-name)

**If You Cannot Annotate the Class**

MOXy offers an external mapping document extension that can be used to apply JAXB metadata to a class that cannot be changed.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml-bindings
    xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
    package-name="**com.common**">
    <java-types>
        <java-type name="City">
            <xml-type name="city2"/>
        </java-type>
    </java-types>
</xml-bindings>
```

Comment: I don't use MOXy in my project. Is there a option to marshalling only the Customer class, without the BaseEntity class?