# How to update XML-TYPE for generated stubs

Tags: java, maven, wsdl, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I am successfully generating java classes from multiple wsdl endpoints using maven-jaxb2-plugin.

This is one execution:

```
                <execution>
                    <id>generateDelta</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                        <generatePackage>com.somepackage1</generatePackage>
                        <schemas>
                            <schema>
                                <url>
                                    wsdl_url
                                </url>
                            </schema>
                        </schemas>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
```

The issue here is that I have multiple executions, thus generating multiple class, each execution saving the classes in different package.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Bapiret2", propOrder = {...})
```

One of the class Babiret2.java is generated in more then one package (so, it comes from multiple  wdsls)

When I execute code that uses this stubs, in a unit test for example I get the following exception:

```
    org.springframework.oxm.UncategorizedMappingException: Unknown JAXB exception; nested exception is com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 2 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Two classes have the same XML type name "{urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style}Bapiret2". Use @XmlType.name and @XmlType.namespace to assign different names to them.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.somepackage1.Bapiret2
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.somepackage2.Bapiret2
```

I found some possible fixes like adding  in configuration under args tag

```
-XautoNameResolution
```

arg, it did not worked

I tested if changing the XmlType name attribute works and it does. Also adding namespace to XmlType works.

The problem is that I do not know how to add this with maven when generating the classes

Comment: I tested if changing the XmlType name attribute works and it does.
Also adding namespace to XmlType works.
The problem is that I do not know how to add this with maven when generating the classes

Answer (score 1):

For each wsdl url, inside the configuration element, you should specify both schemaDirectory and generatePackage elements, that should point to names different from other ones, because of schemaDirectory has as a side effect clearing the specified directory.

Comment: I get the same results

Comment: @aurelius If I said that I don't believe, would be offensive!  
Just in case, post all <configuration> elements in pom.xml.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem belongs to JAXBContext when both classes from different packages, but with the same NameSpace are known by it.
So, there are multiple things you need to consider:

1. Is JAXBContext creation in your hands? If so - do you really need both classes in the same JAXBContext? Maybe you can use two different contexts for each use case? I mean when `Bapiret2` used from `somepackage1` and from `somepackage2`.

If it is not possible:

2. Are those two classes`Bapiret2` generated from the same XSD Schema
   and actual structure is the same?

   if yes - you may need to reconsider your generated packages structure.

   You can generate only one `Bapiret2` class for all your wsdl. There are 
   number of ways to do that usually by adding extra mapping parameters to underlying XJC compiler like

   ```
     -p {namespace}={package Name}
   ```

Just check Plugin documentation how to do that...
(note: there is a side effect: in the package there will be class only from last plugin execution.

3. If `Bapiret2` XML Elements in different XSD have same namespace, but different structure (...unfortunately pretty common case when webservice developers disobey main purpose of namespace ...)
   then it is a worst case.

In that case I use first solution above - different JAXBContexts

But anyway there are some solution below. (I never tried it, but it seems like people are happy with that :-)

[getting-the-jaxb-exception-like-two-classes-have-the-same-xml-type-name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132789/getting-the-jaxb-exception-like-two-classes-have-the-same-xml-type-name)

[extending-jaxb-representing-annotations.html](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/extending-jaxb-representing-annotations.html)

PS. Manual (or through some script) changes after generation still the option...

Comment: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.13.1:generate (generateVehicle) on project maven.module: Error parsing the command line [[-p {namespace}={vehicle}, -episode, C:\...\target\generated-sources\xjc\META-INF\sun-jaxb.episode]]: unrecognized parameter -p {namespace}={vehicle} -> [Help 1]

Comment: <args><arg>-p {namespace}={vehicle}</arg></args>
in the configuration tag

Comment: not like that it is a parameter for xjc command line. {} means put your actual values: i.e `-p http://foo.com/schema/myservice=com.foo.schema.myservice`  Different maven plugins use different configurations to set it and I'm not sure about maven-jaxb2-plugin because I did not use it for such purpose for long time. ... It seems like `<packageName>` settings...